How can I pass parameters from a Streamlit application (button) to a Playwright (python) script?
I'm using two Python libraries to perform a parameter pass from Streamlit (using a button) to Playwright, but I can't get it to work.
In fact, the pass is made, but within the structures synchronous or asynchronous the code presents an error: NotImplementedError.
I would like to know if there is any way to resolve this problem? I'll leave an example of what I'm explaining:
main.py
import streamlit as st

from script import web_script

site='https://www.google.com/'

if st.button("Send"):

    web_script(site)

script.py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def web_script(site):

    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(site)
        print(page.title())
        browser.close()

(venv) PS C:\Users\sergi\OneDrive\02_Dev\projetos\playwright\first> streamlit run main.py    

  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Local URL: http://localhost:8501
  Network URL: http://192.168.0.231:8501

2024-04-20 15:54:17.850 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sergi\OneDrive\02_Dev\projetos\playwright\first\venv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 584, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\sergi\OneDrive\02_Dev\projetos\playwright\first\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    web_script(site)
  File "C:\Users\sergi\OneDrive\02_Dev\projetos\playwright\first\main.py", line 10, in web_script
    with sync_playwright() as p:
  File "C:\Users\sergi\OneDrive\02_Dev\projetos\playwright\first\venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py", line 77, in __enter__
    dispatcher_fiber.switch()
  File "C:\Users\sergi\OneDrive\02_Dev\projetos\playwright\first\venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_context_manager.py", line 56, in greenlet_main
    self._loop.run_until_complete(self._connection.run_as_sync())
  File "C:\Users\sergi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 687, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergi\OneDrive\02_Dev\projetos\playwright\first\venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 263, in run_as_sync
    await self.run()
  File "C:\Users\sergi\OneDrive\02_Dev\projetos\playwright\first\venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 272, in run
    await self._transport.connect()
  File "C:\Users\sergi\OneDrive\02_Dev\projetos\playwright\first\venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 133, in connect
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\sergi\OneDrive\02_Dev\projetos\playwright\first\venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 120, in connect
    self._proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\subprocess.py", line 224, in create_subprocess_exec
    transport, protocol = await loop.subprocess_exec(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1744, in subprocess_exec
    transport = await self._make_subprocess_transport(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 524, in _make_subprocess_transport
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError


This works fine for me, with Ubuntu 20.04, streamlit==1.24.0 and playwright==1.43.0. I see "Google" printed in the streamlit console upon button press, with no error.

I'm using
Windows 11,
Python 3.12.3,
Streamlit version 1.33.0,
Playwright version 1.43.0

I have a vm with ubuntu so I'll try it with your environment. Thank you!

Works fine to me on 1.33.0. I hadn't upgraded Streamlit in awhile.
